# How to choose an air compressor for blowing out a plumbing system?

Tags: plumbing, winterizing

I am designing an outdoor shower, and now I'm thinking about how to winterize the plumbing system. The current design has the system exiting the house, going underground, crossing the back yard, and then going up again to the shower head.

How do I choose an appropriate air compressor for blowing out these water pipes during winter?

I attached a model below with the pipes and its dimensions. Here's a text description to aid with understanding the image. The pipes start at the shut off valve inside the house, and extend 2ft towards the exterior. They take a 90 degree turn towards the ground for 2.5ft. Once underground they take another 90 degree turn to cross the yard for 13.5ft. One last 90 degree turn up out of the ground for 9.5ft to the shower head. The pipes would have an inside diameter of 0.5". I am imagining that the pipes won't have a pitch underground, but open minded if recommended. The dimensions in the model are off due to user error, but the ones in the description above will be the actual ones.

[image: The pipes start at the shut off valve inside the house, and extend 2ft towards the exterior. They take a 90 degree turn towards the ground for 2.5ft. Once underground they take another 90 degree turn to cross the yard for 13.5ft. One last 90 degree turn up out of the ground for 9.5ft to the shower head.]

Comment: Any air compressor blows air.  Your plumbing will not know what model compressor supplied the air blowing into the pipes.

Comment: @RMDman Air compressors have certain characteristics like SCFM, PSI, and tank volume. My question is about how to figure out those requirements given the plumbing system dimensions.

Comment: @ ReyannaBotley, As you can see by the answers below, the specs of the compressor are very unimportant to achieve your goal.

Comment: Side note, I assume/hope the hot pipe will be well insulated below ground?

Comment: If the horizontal run is deep enough you don't need to blow the water out in the first place. All depends on where the frost line is where you live.

Answer (score 5):

Put a valve box in the ground next to the house.  Put drain valves at the bottom of the box.  The 9 foot riser will drain itself.  Then if you blow from the shower head you can use a tiny compressor because you are just blowing out a horizontal pipe.  The pipe exiting the house will also drain itself.

Some gravel at the bottom of the valve box so the water can drain out.

Comment: Oh, I'm starting to see the intuition that I was missing. You're saying that the existing pressure in the pipes will force enough water out the drain valves next to the house? I suppose then that it would be best to pitch the pipes so the lowest point is at these valves, right?

Comment: Put the drain valves at the bottom of the valve box, as close to the level of the horizontal run as possible.  Everything higher than that will drain by itself.   You can try to pitch the 14 foot horizontal run towards the house to *help* drain it, but I think to do it in a way that it will reliably and entirely drain itself will be hard.  14 feet pitched suffieciently, compensating for sagging and then the valves have to be *beneath* the pipe.    That seems like a lot of work.  Just get a small compressor.  You could probably blow it out by mouth! :)

Comment: I have outdoor water spigots that never get drained. The pipe is low enough (and exits via the basement), and the spigots are a special kind that the opening is at the pipe level. I believe they also drain the vertical column to ground when shut off. In other words, very similar to what jay613 is suggesting. Works great, never had a problem with it. If you could have the pipe exit the house where it's already deep enough, and with the right valves at the shower, you wouldn't need to winterize it at all; you could even *use* the shower in winter.

Comment: @Matthew a frost-free spigot [is designed](https://www.angi.com/articles/freeze-proof-faucets.htm) to empty water from the tiny part mounted outside your house and the last 12 inches of pipe inside.   It's automatic because there is a little air admittance valve that allows air to replace the water in the 12 inches of pipe subject to frost.  Everything has to be above ground.  You could rig up something similar if you carefully graded the 14 foot horizontal run and rigged up an air valve above ground that would act on the pipe two feet below ground.  It would be complicated and expensive.

Comment: I'm not talking about those, but about [these](https://blog.boshart.com/how-to-operate-a-yard-hydrant-and-common-uses). Similar principles, though. I don't know if you can get an equivalent tall enough for a shower, but worst case you could get two and plumb some hoses and a secondary mixing valve to them. It'd be very similar to what you're suggesting, but the valves are at the shower and above ground. To winterize, close the valves, pull the hoses off and allow the hoses to gravity-drain. Requires that you can bury the pipes at the house side, though.

Comment: @Matthew That could work, If the 14 foot run is below the frost line.  But they are expensive and you would need one at each end.  I'm sticking with my proposal: A $40 valve box, a couple of $5 drain valves, and (borrowing from another answer) a shop-vac.

Comment: Cost of yard hydrants seems to vary wildly, but cheaper ones start at $50-$60. I have no house-side shutoff, though, but that's because the pipe leaves my house below frost line. I *did* state that as a requirement for doing it that way to be reasonable. Both approaches are similar in operating principles. Yes, yours is cheaper. Mine is more convenient (but might not be feasible) and possibly less prone to catastrophe if someone forgets about it. I don't know which is *better*. 

Answer (score 3):

We used a shopvac when I worked at Comcast. It worked very well.

Comment: Comcast had an employee Lido?  I don't think so.   :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Almost any air compressor should suffice for this job, I think.

- You don't need a lot of pressure (PSI).
- You don't need sustained pressure over a longer time (SCFM).
- And you only need enough volume to displace the water contained in the pipe, maybe a few times over, which even a small tank should be able to handle since it packs the air in at higher pressure.

*WARNING: I did not take thermodemonics, so as Click and Clack would say, the following estimates are "unencumbered by the thought process." Treat them as an exercise in handwaving estimates and wait for someone to correct me... but they seem to suggest I'm right that it doesn't take much of a compressor to do this job. Also, see final notes on ways to simplify the problem.*

Assuming 1/2" *internal* pipe diameter (you didn't tell us if that was ID or OD), the surface area of a slice through the pipe is pi * diameter, or pi/2 square inches. Multiply that by total length of the pipe in inches to get the volume of the water in the pipe in cubic inches; rounding it off to 30' would be 360", so the water volume is 180 * pi cubic inches, or about 566 cubic inches, or about 4 cubic feet.

To convert inches of water (H2O) to PSI multiply the PSI value by 0.036127, so your final 10' rise (again rounding things off) means a pressure at the bottom of about 4.3 PSI.

*Here's where I start distrusting my numbers, and expect someone to correct me... And someone did, thanks @BenVoight*

A typical small compressor's tank can store a cubic foot of air at 100PSI above ambient air pressure. By Boyle's Law, pressure time volume for a gas at the same temperature is constant (though compressing will heat the gas, I'm ignoring that).  We might want to  release that air at about 10 PSI (twice the water pressure, ish). "For Boyle's Law, you need to use absolute gas pressure, so you're talking about 115 PSIa reservoir and 25 PSIa output," which should be about 5 cubic feet of 10PSI pressurized air. But the back-pressure from the water column will decrease as the pipe empties, so I would guess this ought to be plenty to blow most of the water out of that pipe even if some of it trickles back past the blast.

If in doubt, let the tank pump up again and give it another purging. Or consider a compressor with a 2CF tank.

Though...

1. If you can put a valve at the bottom of the system, you can drain it without having to blow it out, which seems *much* easier, either inside the building if you can, or in a buried-but-accessible valve with a reach rod if you can't.
2. Note that the section of pipe which is below the frost line for your area (about 3' deep here) doesn't need to be drained, since it is extremely unlikely to freeze.
3. You might also simplify matters by having valves to let you drain the upright by gravity at ground level, so that much less water, at that much less pressure, needs to be flushed out.

Comment: > If you can put a valve at the bottom of the system, you can drain it without having to blow it out, which seems much easier.

Would this require the pipes to be pitched so the bottom is at the valves, or would it work with no pitch as well?

Comment: @ReyannaBotley Depends on how thoroughly you need to drain the system. See my point about frost line.

Comment: For Boyle's Law, you need to use absolute gas pressure.  So you're talking about 115 PSIa reservoir and 25 PSIa output, and your 1 cubic foot of air becomes less than 5 cubic feet after expansion, not 10.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Ben. I'm a surprised that a 5x compression requires 100PSI, but as I said, I was doing a sem-misinformed spit balling attempt so I'm far from shocked to be wrong. So they might want a 2-cubic-foot compressor, still fairly cheap... Or, as pointed out, they might want to instead plumb in a real drain, even if that means access tube and reach rod.